# The matrix $A-I$ is invertible, suppose $A^2=A$ and show that $A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A_{n\times n}$ over $F$ such that the matrix $A-I$ is invertible. Suppose $A^2=A$, prove that $A=0$.

It's easy to see that $A(A-I)=0=(A-I)A$ I also know that there exist a matrix $B$ such that $B(A-I)=(A-I)B=I$ but I can't find a way to use that. Everything I try leads to $A-A=0$ which doesn't help.

Comment: $0 = B\cdot 0 = B\cdot (A-I)A$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, $$A(A-I) = 0$$and as you also said, there is as $B$ such that $$(A-I)B = I.$$Thus $$A(A-I)B = AI=A=0\cdot B = 0$$

Comment: I'd reorder the last line so the manipluations between each $=$ are elementary (i.e. $A(A-I)B$ will be in the middle and $A$, $0$ at the sides)